# How to insert duplicate key in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a model class with primary key ID.

```
public class Order    
{
    public int ID { get;set }
    public string Product_Name { get;set }
    public string Product_Brand { get;set }
}
```

I want to add the product items in a database where one product can be added more than one time.

Now how can I insert the same product ignoring "duplicate key insertion problem"?? Is there any way to do this??

Help please.

Comment: You seem to have fundamentally misunderstood the purpose of keys. They have to be unique - otherwise they are useless. If you want to add the same product twice add the Product_Name and Product_Brand twice and leave the keys alone.

Comment: What is "ID"? Who defines it? How is it defined in your database? What does _"one product can be added more than one time"_ mean _exactly_? What do two product records for the same product look like _exactly_?

Answer (score 1):

The field `ID` is unique identifier (primary key) of `Order`, you do not have to set this value, it should be autoincremental field. You should to add a new field `ProductID` or just inserting `Product_Name` and `Product_Brand` without `ID` of `Product`

Answer (score -2):

Remove ID column's primary key property. Insert later.

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I press here". Doctor: "Let's remove that finger". Your answer is not a solution.